# Can somebody explain SDF and MACE to me?

Tags: correlation, reference-request

I can't find any information on SDF and MACE save for a vague exert in Kinser's Image Operators books. Therefore I am dumbfounded. I can't understand what they do and what's their role in composite filters. Can somebody please explain them to me? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is allusive at that point: explanation of acronyms (SDF, MACE), need for composite filters... A starting point is  matched spatial filter (MSF). To overcome its limitations, several versions have been proposed. David Casasent is a common denominatoir of the ones you consider.

For the SDF filer, my reference is:

- C. F. Hester and David Casasent, “[Multivariant technique for multiclass pattern recognition](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.19.001758),” Applied Optics, 1980

> A technique for multiclass optical pattern recognition of different
>   perspective views of an object is described. Each multiclass
>   representation of an object is described as an orthonormal basis
>   function expansion, and a single averaged matched spatial filter is
>   then produced from a weighted linear combination of these functions.
>   The technique is demonstrated for a terminal missile guidance
>   application using IR tank imagery.

with comment in:

- J. B. Nelson, "[Multivariant technique for multiclass pattern recognition: comment](https://doi.org/10.1364/AO.20.000008)"

> In a recent article, Hester and Casasent discussed an interesting
>   technique in multiclass pattern recognition. They mentioned that other
>   approaches to the construction of an orthonormal basis function set
>   were possible and specifically suggested the possibility of using a
>   Karhunen-Loéve expansion as an alternative to their own Gram-Schmidt
>   procedure. It is the purpose of this Letter to recommend yet another
>   alternative, the singular value decomposition (SVD), which has very
>   convenient conceptual and numerical advantages, and to show how it may
>   serve as a foundation for future extensions of the theory. The scope
>   of the present discussion is restricted solely to the digital
>   processing aspects of Ref. 1. It will begin with a brief review of the
>   problem in the slightly modified matrix notation that is more
>   compatible with the SVD technique that follows.

- Abhijit Mahalanobis, B. V. K. Vijaya Kumar, and David Casasent, [Minimum average correlation energy filters](https://www.osapublishing.org/DirectPDFAccess/9E0D5EC1-B021-074E-0BFA6865986F1C0C_30657/ao-26-17-3633.pdf?da=1&id=30657&seq=0&mobile=no), Applied Optics, 1987

> The synthesis of a new category of spatial filters that produces sharp
>   output correlation peaks with controlled peak values is considered.
>   The sharp nature of the correlation peak is the major feature
>   emphasized, since it facilitates target detection. Since these filters
>   minimize the average correlation plane energy as the first step in
>   filter synthesis, we refer to them as minimum average correlation
>   energy filters. Experimental laboratory results from optical
>   implementation of the filters are also presented and discussed